# Daylight saving and other timezone related issues with boost date time library

Tags: c++, boost

boost date_time library uses a timezone database file date_time_zonespec.csv. How frequently does this get updated? The dates at which daylight saving start and stop is not the same every year. Does this get accurately reflected in the time zone database?

Comment: Have a look at: https://www.iana.org/time-zones

Comment: @Richard : Thanks for pointing this out. Based on boost repo in github, the time zone was not updated after 2011. This is a matter of concern for me.

Answer (score 1):

For a more actively maintained library, you might want to check out Howard Hinnant's library https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date.

it reads the TZ database directly from IANA or uses a local copy; your choice.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there a documentation/source that can describe how date_time_zonespec.csv file is created from IANA database? My problem is I have a solution which is based on boost library. However, since the database is outdated, it may not be accurate with timezone calculations.